# pq: insert or update on table violates foreign key constraint gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have three tables: AnaData, AnaStepData, and AnaStepInputData. Here are the model mappings for these tables:

```
type AnaData struct {
    ID                string             `gorm:"primary_key;column:ana_ins_id" validate:"max=36"`
    Name              string             `gorm:"column:instance_nm" validate:"max=36"`
    Description       string             `gorm:"column:instance_desc" validate:"max=1000"`
    AnaSteps          []AnaStepData      `gorm:"foreignkey:ana_ins_id"`
}
```

[image]

```
type AnaStepData struct {
    ID               string                   `gorm:"primary_key;column:ana_ins_step_id" validate:"max=36"`
    StepName         string                   `gorm:"column:step_nm" validate:"max=100"`
    AnaInsID         string                   `gorm:"column:ana_ins_id" validate:"max=36"`
    InputParameters  []AnaStepInputData       `gorm:"foreignkey:ana_ins_step_id"`
}
```

[image]

```
type AnaStepInputData struct {
    ID             string `gorm:"primary_key;column:ana_ins_step_input_id" validate:"max=36"`
    AnaStepID      string `gorm:"column:ana_ins_step_id" validate:"max=36"`
    ParameterName  string `gorm:"column:ana_param_nm" validate:"max=100"`
    ParameterValue string `gorm:"column:param_value_txt" validate:"max=1000"`
}
```

[image]

When I try to insert any values using "db.Create(&AnaData) into the AnaData table and respective child tables, I get the following error:

> pq: insert or update on table "ana_ins_step_input" violates foreign
> key constraint "ana_ins_step_input_fk02"

Can anyone shed some light on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Show the data you are used to create and current db table structure.

Comment: Hello Eklavya, Please find the updated table structure, In the model, i have not specified all the mapping here in question but I have that in my code..

Comment: I am able to resolve this issue, I was setting the UUID in the create method where I was saving this nested object for all the objects. I have just moved the setting UUID logic to the hook methods i.e. BeforeCreate hook method and it resolved the issue. Thanks

Comment: You can answer your question also try to do that.